# How do I change a forgotten domain admin password on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, password-recovery

I've tried the SRVANY trick documented [here](http://www.petri.co.il/reset_domain_admin_password_in_windows_server_2003_ad.htm).  After rebooting 3 times into Directory Service Restore mode and tweaking the settings, I have not been able to log-in successfully.  So, I'm not having much luck.  I also saw a reference to [Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/), but from the website it doesn't look like that tool supports Windows Server 2003.

This is an isolated dev system, and it only has one domain administrator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, just a few hours ago I tried exactly that trick - on a Windows 2008 (Core) domain controller. It worked perfectly. Did you use the script linked at the bottom of that guide? Exactly what does "not having much luck" mean?

Comment: No, I was doing the steps manually.  I will see how the script works for me.

Comment: Remember to edit the account name (in one of the script files) to match the domain account you want to change password for, and of course run it in AD restore mode. I think I did a "net start pwdReset" before I rebooted but that should not be needed. If you forget to change the account name you can uninstall the service with instsrv pwdReset REMOVE and try again.

Comment: Yippee! The script, and your tips, worked.

Comment: Wonderful, then two lab systems have been saved by that script today ^^

Answer (score 0):

You have another domain admin reset the password... ;)

Is this the only domain admin account in the domain?